# Angular material date picker output override

Tags: angular, date, angular-material

I'm using the angular material date picker component, with the MomentAdapter.
I'm searching for a way to tell the component to format the date to get a string as value instead of a JS Date or Moment object.

I'm not talking about display values but only for the value that the component would give to a FormGroup or event using (ngModelChange) so there is no need to create a custom control using ControlValueAccessor.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Different locale</mat-label>
  <input name="date" matInput [ngModel]="date" (ngModelChange)="stringValueInsteadOfMomentObject($event)" [matDatepicker]="dp">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
```

I've been searching for a while now without any result.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: stringValueInsteadOfMomentObject() this method when gets called then you want string type format date ?

Comment: Yes exactly, or when using reactives form I would like to get a string from the form values. For now I can't find a way to get anything else than an object, which does not seems practical to send form to the back-end.Thanks !